# Spring integration concurrency - detecting completion

Tags: spring, concurrency, spring-integration, terminate

I have a spring integration workflow that embeds task executors in its channels so as to enable concurrent processing. I manually fire off processing via a gateway and need to block the main thread until all asynchronous processes have completed. Is there a way to accomplish this? I have tried thinking along the lines of barriers, latches, and channel interceptors, but no solution is forthcoming. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, here's what I ended up doing:

- Create a customized ExecutorService that knows when to shutdown - in my case this was simply when releasing the last active thread - i.e. after executing the last piece in the workflow:

```
public class WorkflowThreadPoolExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {
    public WorkflowThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize) {
        super(corePoolSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);

        if (getActiveCount() == 1) {
            shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

- Await executor termination in main thread as follws:

```
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        LOG.error("message=Error awaiting termination of executor", ex);
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Aggregator section from the reference manual:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/htmlsingle/#aggregator

If an aggregator is downstream from the gateway, the gateway caller can block (or use a Future if that's defined as the return type on the gateway interface) until the aggregator has received and released the correlated group of messages, even if those were processed on different threads asynchronously.

Essentially the Aggregator is a barrier itself, and its default release-strategy is essentially a countdown-latch based on the sequence-size of the message group.

Hope that helps.
-Mark

Comment: Hi Mark, Many thanks for this. However, I do not use an aggregator in the workflow. I use a splitter, but merely to batch the input (i.e. from a collection of 150,000 elements, I create batches of 100 elements). One solution I thought of was to extended the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and create a latch off the count of threads leased and pending batches - when they both fall to zero, then open the latch. Not sure if this even works and whether it's as best as one can go in terms of an elegant solution.